# Azure Cosmos DB- Error "Cross partition query is required but disabled"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using below code to fetch a record from the DocumentDB.

Handler:

```
public async Task HandleAsync(EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommand command, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                //delete all existing subscriptions for this user
                await DeleteAllExistingSubscriptions(command.UserId);

                //enable new subscriptions
                if (command.UiNotifications.Any())
                    await AddSubscription(command, SubscriptionAction.UiNotification, command.UiNotifications);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete all existing subscriptions
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userUUId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task DeleteAllExistingSubscriptions(string userUUId)
        {
            var userSubscriptions =  await _subscriptionBaseRepository
                                        .GetItemsAsync(x => x.DistributionUserIds.Contains(userUUId), o => o.PayerNumber);

            if (userSubscriptions.Any())
            {
                var deleteTask = userSubscriptions
                                .Select(userSubscription => _subscriptionBaseRepository.DeleteItemAsync(userSubscription.Id.ToString(), userSubscription.PayerNumber)).ToArray();

                Task.WaitAll(deleteTask);
            }
        }
```

Cosmos DB Repository method GetItemAsync:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByDesc, int takeCount = -1)

        {
            var criteria = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
                    .Where(predicate)
                    .OrderByDescending(orderByDesc)
                    .AsDocumentQuery();

            IDocumentQuery<T> query = criteria;

            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                if (takeCount > -1 && results.Count >= takeCount)
                {
                    break;
                }
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }

            return results;
        }
```

Cosmos DB Repository method: DeleteItemAsync:

```
public async Task DeleteItemAsync(string id, string partitionKey)
        {
            await _client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) });
        }
```

I am getting following error:

> {"Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set
>   x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify
>   x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this
>   exception.\r\nActivityId: 6bd7dd7a-a29c-40c1-a0d2-4599b2d137e8,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.2.0.0, Windows/10.0.17763
>   documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.10.3"}

Stack Trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreClient.<ParseResponseAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreClient.<InvokeAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__159.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__158.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.QueryPlanRetriever.<GetQueryPlanThroughGatewayAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextFactory.<CreateDocumentQueryExecutionContextAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.<ExecuteNextPrivateAsync>d__36`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FleetHub.Notifications.Domain.Repositories.CosmosDBRepository`1.<GetItemsAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\notifications_v2\FleetHub.Notifications\FleetHub.Notifications.Domain\Repositories\CosmosDBRepository.cs:line 106
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FleetHub.Notifications.Commands.Handlers.Subscribers.EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommandHandler.<DeleteAllExistingSubscriptions>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\notifications_v2\FleetHub.Notifications\FleetHub.Notifications.Commands\Handlers\Subscriptions\EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommandHandler.cs:line 45
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at FleetHub.Notifications.Commands.Handlers.Subscribers.EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommandHandler.<HandleAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\notifications_v2\FleetHub.Notifications\FleetHub.Notifications.Commands\Handlers\Subscriptions\EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommandHandler.cs:line 26
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code are getting this exception? In `DeleteItemAsync` method?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS yes I am getting exception in this method

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I am also getting same exception in GetItemAsync

Comment: Can you get a full stack trace? It doesn't make sense that you get this exception on a Delete call, it must be coming from somewhere that also gets called when you are invoking the Delete method.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I have added full stack trace.

Comment: @mjwills I have already set " EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true" in GetItemsAsync method.